# Wildcards - many javascripts?

Tags: javascript, playframework, greenscript

Is there a way to achive in greenscript load all javascripts from one directory? or whole structure?

For example

```
#{greenscript.js 'models/*', output: 'all'/}
```

Comment: Why don't you make a build process that combines them all?

Answer (score 1):

At the moment (Greenscript 1.2.8b) not possible and I am not sure it's a good practice to do that.